# what is the criteria for a scheduled task to run?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-7, scheduled-task

I have a scheduled task that needs to be run 3 times per day.

I have the option between running the task on either a 2008 windows server machine or a windows 7 64 bit regular machine. Both machines may or may not have users logged on to them at any given time.

The process is not intensive at all. It just opens a browser, downloads a small file, and exists.

1. which machine should I schedule this task on?
2. are there any issues with the task running while a user is logged on?
3. is it possible to run the task with nobody logged onto the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do what you wish. However, to make it nice, clean and easy to use on a PC with users logged in or out in variable states, you should use something like cURL to download the small file. Using cURL would allow you to run your task without any need for a pop up window, irrespective of whether a user is logged on or not.

As long as the Windows 7 PC is always on, you are almost certainly better to run this task from there from a security point of view.

You can grab cURL from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html.

Comment: very nice link!! however i cannot just point to a specific file for donwload, my selenium automation tool has to fill in fields and then click a button called EXPORT

Comment: justin, BTW can you please provide some examples on how to use cURL?

Answer (score 1):

1. either will work
2. no issue
3. there is an option to have the task run even when the user is not logged in. whether user is logged in or not. you need to check that.